# Is there a way to get the active pane ID for tmux panes

Tags: bash, tmux

I'm writing a bash script that loops through all the panes I have open and executes several send-keys commands.  Except I want to apply some different logic for the pane I'm executing this script in to prevent send-keys from interrupting the script.

Is there a command to get the ID of the pane I'm currently working in for tmux?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `TMUX_PANE` environment variable is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 16):

There is also `pane_id` format variable that gets expanded to unique pane id.

Example usage:

```
$ tmux run "echo 'This is unique pane id: #{pane_id}'"
```

Comment: For those who may expect to rely on this: it is not true if you have multiple active sessions (i.e., if `tmux choose-tree -s` and `tmux choose-tree -w` show two different things). `${TMUX_PANE}` is safer.

Comment: `#{pane_id}` is the id of the currently active pane and not the pane in which the script was run. Those two can be different in many cases, e.g. if you start running your script and switch the pane in the meantime or if you run the command in a different pane than the active one, e.g. via `tmux send-keys`.